# Use a custom figure as a node shape

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, nodes

There are two similar questions to mine:

- [How to use a tikzpicture as a node shape](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/506591/how-to-use-a-tikzpicture-as-a-node-shape)
- [Use a custom shape as a "building block"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65642/use-a-custom-shape-as-a-building-block)

But they both attempt to draw the node using tikz and I want to use a custom image, since I find drawing the shapes too complicated. What I need is to draw a diagram of a network protocol, where some nodes are people, others are (different classes of) network equipment.  Assuming I want to use existing figures e.g. from LibreOffice Draw, how can I embed the LibreOffice figures into my tikzpicture?

Comment: Maybe try using a `\pic`?

Comment: Put \includegraphics inside a node.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A little example following John Kormylo suggestion. Icons were obtained from [cisco](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/about/brand-center/network-topology-icons.html)

```
\documentclass[border=2mm,tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{chains}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    start chain=going right,
    diagram item/.style={
        on chain,
        join
    }
]
\node [
    diagram item,
    label=center:Internet
] {\includegraphics{cloud}};

\node [
    diagram item,
    label=above:Modem/Router
] {\includegraphics{cable_modem}};

\node [
    diagram item,
    label=above:PC
] {\includegraphics{pc}};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]